# Quarkus Openshift/Kubernetes deployment version update

Tags: maven, kubernetes, deployment, openshift, quarkus

We use Openshift for hosting our containers which we run using an Quarkus runtime. During the build with maven we use then quarkus-openshift maven plugin to generate the Service, Route and Deployment manifests. The issue with a deployment and the match labels for creating pod selectors is that these fields are immutable. By default the quarkus-openshift/quarkus-kubernets plugin adds the application version to the deployment:spec/selector/matchLabels as app.kubernetes.io/version: .

Now when we have an update of the image version/digest we only would like to have the image field updated so that the deployment will use this new version. This is handled properly by the plugin and the files are now updated.

The issue when trying to apply the deployment again to Openshift/Kubernetes an error is returned that the matchLabels are immutable. The end result is then that the deployment has to be removed before the new deployment can be applied, which causes downtime.

Actual question:

- Is there a build argument which I can use to have the plugin not add the application version to the matchLabels
- or can this be added in future versions to have more control on how these files are generated during builds.